# How to implement SSL Pinning with Ktor Muliplatform (KMM)

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

I am venturing into Ktor multiplaform. I want to implement SSL Pinning using Ktor for Android and iOS. I have a .der certificate with keys. I have implemented SSL Pining in native iOS but I don't know the way to do it with Ktor. Does anyone have a notion of how to do this implementation?

I currently have a shared implementation to make requests.

Comment: You can find information about certificate pinning for the Darwin engine here (https://api.ktor.io/ktor-client/ktor-client-darwin/io.ktor.client.engine.darwin.certificates/-certificate-pinner/index.html). Here (https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/CertificatePinner.html) is the documentation of how to configure it for the okHttp client. Here (https://ktor.io/docs/http-client-engines.html#okhttp), you can find the information on how to use a preconfigured OkHttp client instance.